# What is the difference between net.core.netdev_max_backlog and net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog

Tags: ip, tcp, tcpip, sysctl

[Several](https://wiki.mikejung.biz/Sysctl_tweaks) [docs](https://docs.continuent.com/continuent-tungsten-2.0/performance-networking.html) on the net describe these options as following:

**net.core.netdev_max_backlog**:

> Maximum number of packets, queued on the INPUT side, when the interface receives packets faster than kernel can process them.

**net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog**:

> Maximum number of remembered connection requests, which did not yet receive an acknowledgment from connecting client.

But I cannot fully get the difference and relation between these two values. Should `net.core.netdev_max_backlog` be bigger, then `net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog`, or same, or lower?

Comment: Depends on where your bottleneck is.